# bash file contain executable/binary code

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, java, binary

I found this [tool](https://github.com/sterlp/svg2png) and when I downloaded it is a bash executable that contains binary code.
First of all I didn't know this is possible. Does anyone know who this can be done? Also I am not sure how safe generally this is since I can't really be sure what the bash file contains

Comment: That looks like a Java program to me. What do you mean by "bash file"? Do you mean "script"? What file in that repository are you actually referring to?

Comment: @Kusalananda: The tool is here https://github.com/sterlp/svg2png/releases I am referring to the `svg2png`. Download it and view it with an editor. The first line is `exec java -Xmx1G -jar "$0" "$@"` and the rest is binary data

Comment: Don't post information like that in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: That's a combined file which is both a valid shell script and a zip (jar) file. The java command in it will just unpack it. You can also try with `unzip -l svg2png` to see its content ;-)

Comment: I don't see anything strange with that. That's a Java program provided as a JAR file with a shell wrapper. The alternative way of doing it would have been to have a separate shell script that does the `exec` but using the other file (which would be a `.jar` file). No difference.

Comment: @mosvy it won’t unpack it, it will run the Java program contained within.

Comment: @StephenKitt right, sorry. Same as `java -jar myself.jar`.

Comment: I did not know that was possible. Can someone write some answer with a reference on this and so I can accept it? I do see content when I run `unzip -l svg2png` but I don't get how this works. The first line basically says run `java svg2png` with the shell parameters. But I don't understand how the unpacking etc works there

Comment: The "magic" is that the shell will interpret a script line by line from the _beginning_ of the file, but any zip/jar unpacker will look for a "central directory" at the _end_ of the file (which also specifies the start of the actual archive relative to it).

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar - a shell script with a small amount of code in it to extract binary/uuencoded/etc data (mostly uuencoded because mail and news often had to pass through systems that weren't ["8-bit clean"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_clean)) from the remainder of the same file.  a self-extracting archive.  Sharing binary files like this used to be quite common long ago, in email and on usenet newsgroups etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a self-contained Java program which relies on a few “tricks”:

- Java programs can be packaged as JAR files, which are ZIP files containing a manifest (`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`) which specifies the Java class to start;
- `java -jar`, given a JAR file, will look at the manifest and start the corresponding class, loading any other required resources from the JAR file and the Java runtime (one can also specify another class to run, but that’s not relevant here);
- ZIP files can start with arbitrary data; this is how self-extracting executables work (executable ZIP files which will extract themselves when run).

So `svg2png` is a JAR file, but with a prepended shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec java -Xmx1G -jar "$0" "$@"
```

When run, this will run a shell, which will then replace itself with `java -Xmx1G -jar` and the name of the “script” (`svg2png` with whatever path was used), and any arguments. `-Xmx1G` sets the heap size, and `-jar` tells the JVM to “run” the given JAR file, `svg2png` in this case. The rest of `svg2png` is the JAR file; in particular, it contains the following manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: sterlp
X-Compile-Target-JDK: 1.8
X-Compile-Source-JDK: 1.8
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_51
Main-Class: org.sterl.svg2png.Main
```

This instructs the JVM to run the `org.sterl.svg2png.Main` class, which starts the program.

You’ll find more details about the ZIP format [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Structure), in particular the structure description which shows how the format allows arbitrary data at the start of the file (and in other positions). ZIP files are identified by their “central directory”, which resides at *the end* of the file.